# Evaluating $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin^{2n+1}(x)\cos(x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> I have to find
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin^{2n+1}(x)\cos(x)$$

Answer given is $0$.

I tried applying L'Hospital's rule and this is what I got:
$$((2n+1)\sin^2n(x)-2\sin^{2n+2}(x)(n+1))/(-1/n^2)$$

How should I proceed from here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have $2$ variables?

Comment: No, only as n tends to infinity.

Comment: You can't use L'Hospital's rule here, it only applicable for f(x)/g(x) form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit is $0$, for any $x\in\Bbb R$:

- If $x\in\frac\pi2+\pi\Bbb Z$, then $\cos(x)=0$, and therefore your limit is $0$.
- Otherwise, $|\sin(x)|<1$, and therefore your limit is $0$ too, since$$|r|<1\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}nr^{2n+1}=0.$$

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer my question.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.